# C#.NET using block

Tags: c#, using-statement

I want to use the "using" block in my DAL layer. Like

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
{
     Command object
     Reader object
}
```

Since the SqlConnection object in initialised in the using block i know that this connection object will be automatically disposed when the control exits the using block scope.

But i am creating Command and Reader objects inside the using block. Do i have to explicitly close them or do i have to write another "using" block for them.

Comment: Not sure.But need not write another "using" block.After block scope is over objects:Command & Reader  will be disposed.

Comment: @Pratik, only object explicitly put in the `using (...)` parentheses are actually disposed. Here, the Command and Reader will not be disposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `using` for the Command and Reader as well, or explicitly close them.

I normally code it like this:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn)) {
}
```

This limits the number of identations.

Answer (score 3):

You typically write using-blocks for those as well, ie.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from table";
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's worth writing a using block for any code that supports IDisposable interface.  This way you ensure that you have done what you can to release any scarce resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `using` blocks for any item that implements `IDispose`. So you can make nested `using` blocks for each of these, within the block for the connection, to ensure that they are properly disposed of after use.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `using()` or `finally` blocks if you don't like using for your connections and readers. For readers, connection isn't closed until the reader is closed. Also I've read that `using()` doesn't 100% guarantee you that the connection will be closed but I don't know the reason behind that since it is converted to try - finally blocks and will be executed in any condition.