# How does the sql process behave?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

From my C# program, I open the sql connection and do some updates to tables. After that I close the connection. And, If I check under Activity Monitor in Management Studio, New Process is created and even though I closed my sql connection from the program, the process is still there in Activity Monitor. May I know how this process behaves? Do we need to clear these processes explicitly? Thanks.

Comment: I'm using sql server 2008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are using the concept of *process* incorrectly here.

ADO.NET uses a [`connection pool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx). This means that when you call the `Open` method on a SqlConnection instance, you are not opening a new physical connection to the database, you are simply drawing one from the existing pool. And when you call `Close` you are not closing the connection, you are simply returning it to the connection pool for reuse.

The connection pool lives in the process of your application and is per connection string.

> Do we need to clear these processes explicitly?

No, all you have to do is to ensure that you have wrapped all your `IDisposable` resources (such as as connections and commands) in `using` statements. This way you don't even need to be explicitly calling the Close method and the code will ensure that everything is properly disposed even in case of exception:

```
string connectionString = ...
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM foo";
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("id"));
            Console.WriteLine(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.Is it necessary to use command obj and reader object in using? Putting connection ojb in using block is enough?

Comment: i saw this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487743/c-net-using-block . According to this, it's necessary

Comment: Yes, it is necessary, exactly as shown in my answer. Every class that you are manipulating and which implements the `IDisposable` interface must be wrapped in a `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you dispose the connection, your best bet is a using()-block.

```
using ( var con = new SqlConnection("???") )
{
   using ( var cmd = con.CreateCommand() )
   {
      // do SQL with cmd
   }
}
```